# Pytest-Django Client User Login

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I was wondering if someone can help figure out why it seems my user is not being logged in.

```py
import pytest
from mixer.backend.django import mixer


@pytest.fixture
def strong_pass():
    return "Str#410-P@55"


@pytest.fixture
def create_test_user(db, strong_pass):
    return mixer.blend('auth.User', username="JohnnyTest", password=strong_pass)


@pytest.fixture
def logged_in_client(client, create_test_user, strong_pass):
    test_user = create_test_user
    if test_user is not None:
        client.login(username=test_user.username, password=strong_pass)
        return client, test_user
```

It makes the user fine and can reference him in other tests, but client doesn't seem to like the login.

I have tried to replace the values in client.login to the exact strings and it still doesn't work. I have also tried force_login but still not working

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the main issue was happening because of mixer.

Once I followed the normal docs for login on pytest-django docs, I got my fixture working.

https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#client-django-test-client